# How to install Python 2.7 devel if I have Python 2.7 in a different directory

Tags: python, dependencies, development-environment

I have python 2.7 installed in `/opt/python2.7`.
Now i want to install the devel packages for it but could not find it.

How can i install it os that goes in python2.7 not for default python2.4

Comment: Do you remember how you installed it in the first place?

Comment: i did this `./configure --prefix=/opt/python2.7 --enable-shared`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing Python from source installs the development files in the same prefix.